# Can a Sequel model have Array attributes?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I want to create a `Sequel::Model` that has an array attribute. I have added a `varchar[]` column to the table, and I can successfully update records using `Sequel::Dataset::update`. However, if I try to set the attribute on a model instance and save it, I get an error:

```
2.1.1 :048 > a = Sequel.pg_array(['public'])
 => ["public"]
2.1.1 :049 > DB[:oauth_access_tokens].where(id: 1).update(scopes: a)
I, [2014-06-19T09:53:49.009563 #40260]  INFO -- : (0.003404s) UPDATE "oauth_access_tokens" SET "scopes" = ARRAY['public'] WHERE ("id" = 1)
 => 1
2.1.1 :050 > token = AccessToken.find(id: 1)
I, [2014-06-19T09:53:52.438038 #40260]  INFO -- : (0.000771s) SELECT * FROM "oauth_access_tokens" WHERE ("id" = 1) LIMIT 1
 => #<AccessToken @values={:id=>1, :resource_owner_id=>2, :application_id=>1, :token=>"ec73426e2be81ab4772e67e139430d3896d705bcee6c141a38bd0e903e5df3eb", :refresh_token=>nil, :expires_in=>7200, :revoked_at=>nil, :created_at=>2014-06-06 12:37:07 -0400, :scopes=>["public"]}>
2.1.1 :051 > token.scopes = a
 => ["public"]
2.1.1 :052 > token.save
I, [2014-06-19T09:54:02.261076 #40260]  INFO -- : (0.000332s) BEGIN
E, [2014-06-19T09:54:02.262007 #40260] ERROR -- : PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: missing dimension value
LINE 1: ..." = '2014-06-06 12:37:07.485542-0400', "scopes" = '["public"...
                                                         ^: UPDATE "oauth_access_tokens SET "resource_owner_id" = 2, "application_id" = 1, "token" = 'ec73426e2be81ab4772e67e139430d3896d705bcee6c141a38bd0e903e5df3eb', "refresh_token" = NULL, "expires_in" = 7200, "revoked_at" = NULL, "created_at" = '2014-06-06 12:37:07.485542-0400', "scopes" = '["public"]' WHERE ("id" = 1)
I, [2014-06-19T09:54:02.262691 #40260]  INFO -- : (0.000229s) ROLLBACK
Sequel::DatabaseError: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  missing dimension value
LINE 1: ..." = '2014-06-06 12:37:07.485542-0400', "scopes" = '["public"...
```

Is what I want to do even possible with Sequel's support for postgres array types? If so, how can I allow setting `token.scopes` to either an `Array` or a `Sequel::Postgres::PGArray` and successfully save the model?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627010/inserting-an-array-using-sequel-gem-in-postgresql) seems like the same issue.  It looks like there is an extension needed for this to work, take [a look at this documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array_rb.html).

edit: According [to this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sequel-talk/rIEplp0QPM0), maybe adding `Sequel::Model.db.extension :pg_array` will do the trick?

Comment: Not the same issue; I'm using the extension already (as you can see from the invocation of the `Sequel.pg_array` method)

Comment: Found something else that may be of value in that case...  See edit.

Comment: Still the case that using the extension isn't the problem. I can use the extension just fine to update the database if I go through the dataset interface. The problem is the extension does not seem to integrate with the `Sequel::Model` class.